# Can't get serial port working (header pins, Raspberry Pi 1 Model B)

Tags: serial, raspbian-wheezy

I have read quite a lot of tutorials and tips about the issue, but serial port just doesn't work. There has to be some configuration that I have missed.

**The setup**

Raspberry Pi 1 Model B (oldest revision, with Ethernet port)

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
```

I used python to send some random data to serial port while scoping TX pin with my oscilloscope. TX pin was always high.

Python snippet:

```
import serial
port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=9600, timeout=3.0)
port.write("qwerty")
```

**Done so far**

I modified cmdline.txt so that ttyAMA0 won't be used for serial console

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /boot/cmdline.txt
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p6 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
```

I also commented out ttyAMA0 form inittab

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /etc/inittab | grep ttyAMA0
#T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100
```

Finally I modified /boot/config.txt by adding line "enable_uart=1" which should make sure that serial port pins are in correct mode after boot. This was double checked with gpio.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ gpio readall
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+-Model B1-+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   |  1 || 2  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   2 |   8 |   SDA.1 | ALT0 | 1 |  3 || 4  |   |      | 5v      |     |     |
 |   3 |   9 |   SCL.1 | ALT0 | 1 |  5 || 6  |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   4 |   7 | GPIO. 7 |   IN | 0 |  7 || 8  | 1 | ALT0 | TxD     | 15  | 14  |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   |  9 || 10 | 1 | ALT0 | RxD     | 16  | 15  |
 |  17 |   0 | GPIO. 0 |   IN | 0 | 11 || 12 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 1 | 1   | 18  |
 |  27 |   2 | GPIO. 2 |   IN | 0 | 13 || 14 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |  22 |   3 | GPIO. 3 |   IN | 0 | 15 || 16 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 4 | 4   | 23  |
 |     |     |    3.3v |      |   | 17 || 18 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 5 | 5   | 24  |
 |  10 |  12 |    MOSI |   IN | 0 | 19 || 20 |   |      | 0v      |     |     |
 |   9 |  13 |    MISO |   IN | 0 | 21 || 22 | 0 | IN   | GPIO. 6 | 6   | 25  |
 |  11 |  14 |    SCLK |   IN | 0 | 23 || 24 | 0 | IN   | CE0     | 10  | 8   |
 |     |     |      0v |      |   | 25 || 26 | 0 | IN   | CE1     | 11  | 7   |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
 | BCM | wPi |   Name  | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name    | wPi | BCM |
 +-----+-----+---------+------+---+-Model B1-+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
```

ttyAMA0 is present

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ls -l /dev | grep ttyAMA0
crw-rw---T 1 root dialout 204,  64 Jan 27 08:42 ttyAMA0
```

And user is in dialout group

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ groups
pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users netdev i2c input indiecity spi gpio
```

I can switch serial port pins high and low with GPIO-library, so they are working electrically.

I would appreciate any help.

**Solved**

It turned out that my test was just bad. Serial port was probably working all the time.

First I copied file to dev/ttyAMA0 and scoped it. Port was working as expected.

Next I put feedback link from TX to RX and made small Python program that wrote text continously to serial port and read the input buffer at the same time. I got text back as expected. I also saw data in the scope.

Lessons learned: use proper test scripts or stand alone program for testing.

Thanks for the help and sorry for the hassle :)

Comment: Have you tried anything other than the oscilliscope, e.g., a feedback loop (connect tx to rx)?

Comment: I am quite familiar with the scope, so I am 99% sure that TX pin just don't do its thing. I can try TX to RX feedback, but I can't understand what this would help/proof.

Comment: You are using Wheezy, but have obviously also been reading tutorials about current Raspbian - anything posted after mid 2015 is not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "test" your port you NEED a realistic test program.

It unclear what your missing program does, but `serial.write` will NOT actually output anything! I will (probably) put 6 characters in the buffer. It doesn't cost any more to output a continuous stream - try `writelines`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending data direct to the device:

`cp some_file /dev/ttyAMA0`

At least that tells you if the UART TX port has not been damaged.